# ActionBar setBackgroundDrawable force close

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-actionbar, themes

Good day guys,My apps forced close and i get the log cat like this.
I think the problem will be at Line 51 according to the LogCat but I have no idea why is it wrong.

The code at Line 51 will be :

```
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00C4CD")));
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // c = MainActivity.this;
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00C4CD")));
```

LogCat

```
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342): Process: com.fyp.atms, PID: 17342
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fyp.atms/com.fyp.atms.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:805)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at com.fyp.atms.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-07 18:25:40.526: E/AndroidRuntime(17342):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
```

Tried to add this in my values-> style.xml but still not working.

```
<resources>

    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">#00C4CD</item>
    </style> 



    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

LogCat after adding the styles.xml

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fyp.atms/com.fyp.atms.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Comment: Your code seems correct to me, have to tried adding the actionbar from support v7 package? Also adding support package will requires changes in the style file, simple use AppCompact theme along with the below change in the main activity file.

ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();

    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00C4CD")));

Comment: I get this after getting from support v7
11-07 21:04:38.606: E/AndroidRuntime(23340): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fyp.atms/com.fyp.atms.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content

Comment: Are you trying to request some window property after calling set content view? if yes, please provide your present code now.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and came up with the following implementation which worked in my case...

In AndroidManifest.xml, use the `Theme.AppCompat` style in the activity.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    ...
```

In the MainActivity.java code, make sure to 1) import the v7 `ActionBarActivity`, 2) have the activity extend `ActionBarActivity`, 3) use the corresponding v7 bar and `getSupportActionBar()` method.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

...

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(bar != null){
            bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3f4deb")));
        }
    }
```

This is based on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html.  I wasn't able to get the API 11 and higher methods to work, but the above solution was sufficient for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

before ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

Comment: Not working, after adding the code u gave, the error point back to ur code (Line 50) instead of my (Line 51)

Comment: Are you sure that you have properly added ActionBar? Because you nullpointer is at bar

Comment: Im just using the 2 lines of codes for the ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00C4CD"));
```

Comment: It doesnt work, curly underline appear under the setBackgroundColor and request me to change to setBackgroundDrawable.